# Xamarin Forms - Listview Binding Update row UI

Tags: android, ios, forms, xamarin

I'm having a problem in the listview with Binding, The problem i'm having is:

- I have a list of object, each row with and decrement button, a text of the quantity and a increment button.
- When this list loads and I click the increment button, the text quantity is incremented by 1 <- Correct
- When I scrolldown and click in a increment button randomly, the text quantity is not incremented (the Binding object has the value incremented, but the UI doesn't update), and when i click again, the value is incrementeded and it shows 2 in screen, in other words, just the second time I click the UI is updated. <- This is the problem

In some tests that I've done, following the above topic that i explained the problem, when I scroll up (the sufficient to the row with the problem hide from the device screen) and scroll down again to the same position, when I click the increment button, the same thing happens, I need to click twice so the UI is updated to 4.

I'm using Prism MVVM, the code below is inside a class for the items in ItemSource.

```
[JsonIgnore]
private int _quantity;
[JsonIgnore]
[Ignore]
public int Quantity {
    get {
        return _quantity;
    } set {
        SetProperty(ref _quantity, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TextQuantity));
    }
}

[JsonIgnore]
[Ignore]
public string TextQuantity
{
   get
   {
        return string.Format("Total: {0}", Quantity);
   }
}

[JsonIgnore]
[Ignore]
public ICommand ClickPlus
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            Quantity += 1;
        });
    }
}
```

In short, if I scroll the list view and try to interact with the UI in one row only, the user needs to interact twice, so the row UI is updated.

[image: here's the gif of what its happening.]

Comment: at the 3º click, does the Quantity value 3 or 2?, and does it show on the UI in the same click?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais if I Click once, the value is updated, but in the UI is still 0, so I need to click again, and then the UI shows the value 2, and when I click again, everything works perfectly, except when I scroll up and go back again, then the first click do not update the UI again =[

Comment: hmm, thats really strange, does RaisePropertyChanged called on the first click?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais yes, I have debugged also, forced a try catch, and nothing happens =[

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to update ListView data when click Button in ListView row. I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label
                                x:Name="label1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Text="{Binding quality}" />
                            <Button
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.command, Source={x:Reference listview1}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                Text="increment" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page24 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<model31> models { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand1 command { get; set; }

    public Page24 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        models = new ObservableCollection<model31>()
        {
            new model31(){Id=1, name="cherry",quality=12},
            new model31(){Id=2,name="barry",quality=31},
            new model31(){Id=3,name="Wendy",quality=25},
            new model31(){Id=4,name="Amy",quality=32}               

        };
        command = new RelayCommand1(obj=>method1((int)obj));
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public void method1(int Id)
    {
        IEnumerable<model31> list = models.Where(x => x.Id == Id);

        foreach(model31 m in list)
        {
            m.quality = m.quality + 1;
        }
    }

}
```

**RelayCommand1 class**, to implement command:

```
 public class RelayCommand1 : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

}
```

**ViewModelBase class**, to implement notify.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try that, but what I do now is use the command inside the item object, I'll try to put the command to the viewmodel that contains the list, and i'll give you a feedback, thank you

Comment: It didn't work =[, in your sample (in case you still have it) try to add a big list (with about 40 items), then scroll down until the middle of the scroll, and click "Increment", it will probably not increment the first time, you need to click twice

Comment: @Marcio, I have 40 items according to your requirements. The gif has been updated. It works fine.

Comment: I've updated my question, can you see the gif that I've uploaded? it shows exactly whats happening, thank you for your attention

Comment: @Marcio, can you provide one demo that can reproduce your issue here?